# python id() function equvivalent for scala 3?

Tags: python, scala

I have been Googling around to see if I can find a function like id() in Python which returns a unique id for an object. Does anyone know if this exists?

Comment: Maybe `hashCode`? Although, it would be better if you can explain what is the meta problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @j1-lee The OP is asking for a solution in Scala, not Python.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of other requirements, I think that [Java's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) `System.identityHashCode()` will accomplish what you're looking for.

However, note that (just as in Python!) it's hard to predict exactly when different objects will have the same identity hashcode, due to things like inlining:

```scala
scala> val x = 1
x: Int = 1

scala> val y = 1
y: Int = 1

scala> (System.identityHashCode(x), System.identityHashCode(y))
res0: (Int, Int) = (198625530,198625530)

scala> val x = 1729
x: Int = 1729

scala> val y = 1729
y: Int = 1729

scala> (System.identityHashCode(x), System.identityHashCode(y))
res1: (Int, Int) = (46967127,642830322)
```

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the answer! This works great. How does scala 3 under the hood check for reference equality, i.e. pointers/references to the same object?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What "userspace" operation do you have in mind whose hood you're trying to peek under?